# SSO re-authentication is blocked with CORS error

Tags: javascript, cors, sapui5, saml-2.0, sap-basis

We have a UI5 web app that sits on a gateway server (my.sap.gateway.server.com). We are not using web dispatcher.

The issue we have is as follows:

- User logs onto the UI5 web app
- They are redirected to SSO to login
- User is able to use web app and enters details/takes pictures
- User is inactive for 30minutes
- They come back to finish their work (e.g. click ‘Submit Work’) but their ‘session’ has timed out
- Their service request gets automatically redirected to SSO by SAP to create a new session.
- That redirect request is blocked with a CORS issue as sso.server.com doesn’t accept requests from my.sap.gateway.server.com (where the app is sitting)

**Error Message:**
Failed to load sso.server.com/.... Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin my.sap.gateway.server.com is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: we are investigating adding a reverse proxy